# "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, browser-cache

"Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" when I logout and try to login in the same page.

In the above case, login to application is successful, and when I logout from application, the login page is displayed again. Problem is: when I tried to login again in same page, it shows **Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up**

Login Url (fresh, 1st time): **//firco/en_US/** d
Logput URL (where login page  is displayed again): **//firco/en_US/logout/**

I want to use same driver (browser instance) for 1st and 2nd login.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("//Continuity/en_US/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement uname = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='text-input-element-15']"));
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('text-input-element-16')"));
WebElement busunit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('text-input-element-22')"));
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login-button"));
uname.sendKeys("RAGHU");
pwd.sendKeys("Hello00");
login.click();
WebElement LogoutButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='logout-button']"));
LogoutButton.click();
driver.get("//Continuity/en_US/");
uname.sendKeys("SUGU");
```

In above code I want to user uname at both 1st and 2nd login (after logout), in same driver

Comment: This is because the page has refreshed after it logged out. You will need to `findElement` on the login elements again.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Anand S ...I have added my code for your reference..

Answer (score 4):

Web elements you stored before clicking on login button will not be present in cache after login because of page refresh or page changes. You need to again store these web elements in order to make them available again under cache. I have modified your code a bit which might help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("//Continuity/en_US/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement uname = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='text-input-element-15']"));
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('text-input-element-16')"));
WebElement busunit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('text-input-element-22')"));
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login-button"));
uname.sendKeys("RAGHU");
pwd.sendKeys("Hello00");
login.click();
WebElement LogoutButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='logout-button']"));
LogoutButton.click();
driver.get("//Continuity/en_US/");
uname = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='text-input-element-15']"));
uname.sendKeys("SUGU");
```

Comment: It worked out when the element is identified again in the same driver.. But a modal dialog is shown after logout and url is loaded again

Comment: I don't know whether it's good practice to get the value of element again or not, but it works. Thank you!

Comment: Well explained. Is there any documentation about this? @mfsi